# About bounce handling for email relay mails

Tags: jakarta-mail, emailrelay

Hi am going to implement email relay in my company and also providing bounce handling mechanism by specifying return path  as my mail box.But what is the problem means i get bounce report as in mail body for some providers and some providers give them as attachment like godaddy.

If i send a mail with multiple attachments and when they get bounced the bounced mail contains those attachments plus bounced mail header as another attachment ..How to handle the situation???or any other bounce handling mechanism for email relay bounced mails

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no consistency in how mail servers handle bounce messages.
There's an internet standard for such Delivery Status Notifications, but
not all mail servers follow it.  You're going to need heuristics in your
application to handle the common cases.